Try to make and edge texture in shader
I want to create an edge texture that gives a sharp/used effect. In this picture, it works, but the object has a 'flat' effect when I'm in smooth mode. Does anyone know how I can fix this?


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Can you please elaborate on what you're looking for? Is an "edge texture" something that highlights the outline of the object (like the orange border seen in your picture)? Are you trying to draw dark lines along the edges of your object, like a wireframe?
